# Diffeomorphisms of a "matrix type"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, matrices, lie-groups

Let $\exp$ denote the matrix exponential map, let $Y\subset C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$ be defined the collection of all functions of the form
$$
f(x) = \exp\left(
\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) A_i
\right)x,
\qquad f_i \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^d,[0,1]), A_i \in \mathfrak{gl}_d(\mathbb{R})
.
$$
**Edit:**
What additional constrains do I need on $f_i$ so that $f$ is a diffeomorphism and $Y$ is dense in the subset of $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$ of diffeomorphisms fixing $0$?  Or is it just dense in some space of embeddings?

Comment: Is it just me or why is it cleat that Y is even a subset of the diffeomorphisms? On one hand the matrix exponential is non-injective and having thought a while about this I do not see why the resulting mapping will be injective in general.

Comment: I made some edits.  Basically I want to approximate all diffeomorphisms using a set of smooth modified matrix functions.

Comment: @New_Topologist_On_The_Block If $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ is such a map, is it obvious that the derivative $Df : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathfrak{gl}_d(\mathbb{R})$ is pointwise invertible, so that $f$ is at least everywhere a local diffeomorphism?